# C/C++ Duplicate header file names from different projects

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a project that uses libraries developed by different organizations.  Call them lib_a and lib_b.  For each of these libraries I need to include their respective header files: lib_a.h, lib_b.h

It turns out that each of these libraries has a header file with the same name (but not the same content) which is included from their respective header file - call it foo.h

So on my compile, I have something like this:

g++ -I/path/to/lib_a/headers -I/path/to/lib_b/headers ... myfile.cc -o myfile.o

Where myfile.cc includes lib_a.h and lib_b.h

The problem is that, since the path to the lib_a headers is listed first, the foo.h from lib_a is loaded.  Which isn't appropriate for lib_b

I know I could change the include statements in lib_a.h and lib_b.h to specify a unique path to their respective foo.h  But then I would have to do that edit every time I get a new copy of lib_a or lib_b.  And anybody else that wants to build my project would have to modify their lib_a and lib_b installs.  It seems there should be a better way, but my google-fu doesn't know how to ask the question.

Comment: Is it possible to split myfile.cc into a part that uses lib_a.h and a part that uses lib_b.h?

Comment: Not really - this is simplified for the sake of clarity.  In reality, they'll be pretty intertwined.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think your only reliable way of doing this is to split them and use wrapper classes and proxy functions to make them independent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
g++ -I/path/to/lib_a/headers -I/path/to/lib_b/headers .
```

you shall add just one path

```
g++ -I/path/to .
```

And in your sources to use explicit name of each header:

```
#include "lib_a/headers/foo.h"
#include "lib_b/headers/foo.h"
```

Comment: Yea, that will definitely work.  It's what I'm going to do so I can keep making progress.  But as I said in the question, it feels like a hack - I'll be modifying the source code of the 3rd party libraries.  Which will break every time I update the library.  And will require other users to make the modification as well.  Looking for a better way, and I figure I'm not the first person to run into this.

Comment: You don't need to modify their side in this case, why?

Comment: because foo.h is included from lib_a.h and lib_b.h  So I'd have to modify those files to add the specific path.